# Draw a circuit figure according to (¬ ∧ ) ∨ ¬( ∨ ) expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to draw a circuit figure as the title says. I have downloaded a Circuit Diagram program, but would like some input on how to do this?

Comment: Think about how you would evaluate the statement given values of $P$, $Q$, and $R$ ... you would take the value of $P$, and apply the negation to it. Then you would take that value and also the value of $Q$, and apply the $\land$ operation on those two values ... etc.  The circuit should follow that kind of thinking

Answer (score 1):

You've got **and**, **or** and **not** gates in the circuit, which take inputs and produce outputs.

You've got **and**, **or** and **not** operations in the given expression, which take inputs and produce outputs.

If two things are **and**-ed together in the expression, use them as inputs to an **and** gate, and so on.

For example, if your expression contains $A \land B$, you'll have an **and** gate which has $A$ and $B$ as its inputs and $A\land B$ as its output. If $A$ and $B$ are subexpressions, then they'll come from the outputs of the gates that implement the subexpressions.

It really is that straightforward. One logic gate for each operator, and the structure of the expression tells you how to wire them up.

(Well it is until you start needing to eliminate race conditions, anyway. But that amounts to just adding extra terms to the expression.)

Comment: Is something like this correct? https://scontent.ftrd3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/s2048x2048/51407863_870600509998489_1151599861565489152_n.png?_nc_cat=110&_nc_ht=scontent.ftrd3-1.fna&oh=1167507ec59d00819356d769f7d2edb4&oe=5CEB4746

Comment: Forgot the not gate for qr

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. (But you've missed one of the NOTs out.) Once you're sure it matches the expression, just replace your blobs with the appropriate circuit symbols.

Comment: You've got it. :-) But you don't need two each of the P and Q inputs to the whole thing—have one and connect it to both gates that use it.

Comment: Correction: "dont need two Q inputs".(The expression isn't displaying properly for me—I'm seeing a version with the variable names missing.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: You're welcome! When I first met this I loved the fact that you can basically calculate the circuit as a formula. :-)